# FindBugs in Java code with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, findbugs

I'm new in the Gradle's world and I'm trying create a project with FindBugs

I found that I need to declare those lines inside build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

findbugs {    
    effort = "max"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/findbugs")
    reportLevel = "high"
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
}

findbugsMain {
    reports {       
        html.enabled = true
        xml.enabled = false
    }
}
```

When I execute gradle build the report page is generate however without any error message. To test FindBug, I put the below code inside my classes to test

```
if("1" == "1"){

}
```

My reports don't give any problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe FindBugs doesn't consider that as a problem, given that these are two String literals, guaranteed to indeed be `==`. Try with `Integer.toString(23) == "24"` instead.

Comment: @JBNizet, that's not the problem - see my response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your code:

```
if("1" == "1") { }
```

doesn't raise any violation.

Secondly, the following line:

```
reportLevel = "high"
```

will cause only really *problematic* bugs to be reported, as described [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs:reportLevel).

To prove it I've prepare a [sample project](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/28240415). Try running it with `reportLevel = "high"` commented out and left as is. When it's commented out `findbugs` task will fail because of nasty variable name.

Comment: looking in the findbug's bug description I was trying simulate that one http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ES_COMPARING_STRINGS_WITH_EQ however, removing the reportLevel solve my doubt of other bugs errors in my code. Thx a lot